Calculate camera y position for horizon to be at a percentage of canvas height
I have the following three.js code that renders a cube hovering above a floor, with the camera looking at the cube:


let renderer, camera, scene, light, floor, cube;

init();
render();
  
function init() {
  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
  
  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(50, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
  scene = new THREE.Scene();
  scene.background = new THREE.Color('skyblue');
  
  light = new THREE.DirectionalLight('white', 3);
  light.position.set(15, 10, 20);
  light.castShadow = true;
  light.shadow.camera.zoom = 2;
  scene.add(light);

  floor = new THREE.Mesh();
  floor.geometry = new THREE.CircleGeometry(camera.far);
  floor.material = new THREE.MeshToonMaterial({ color: 'forestgreen' });
  floor.rotation.x = THREE.MathUtils.degToRad(-90);
  floor.receiveShadow = true;
  scene.add(floor);
  
  cube = new THREE.Mesh(); 
  cube.geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(); 
  cube.material = new THREE.MeshPhysicalMaterial({ color: 'red' });
  cube.position.set(0, getCubeY(), 0);
  cube.castShadow = true;
  scene.add(cube);

  // Look at the cube with the horizon being at 80% screen height.
  camera.position.set(0, getCameraY(0.8), 4);
  camera.lookAt(cube.position);
}

function render() {
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
  cube.rotation.y += 0.01;
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

function getCubeY() {
  // In my real world scenario this is dynamic.
  return 2;
}

function getCameraY(horizonPercent) {
  // Don't know how to calculate this.
  // Hardcoded to an approximation of 80% for now.
  return 3.1;
}
<script type="importmap">
  {
    "imports": {
      "three": "https://unpkg.com/three@0.164.1/build/three.module.js"
    }
  }
</script>
<script type="module">
import * as THREE from 'three';
window.THREE = THREE; // lol
</script>



What I'm struggling with is how to implement the getCameraY function. I want the horizon to be positioned at a specified percentage of the canvas height. For example if I were to specify horizonPercent = 0.2:

horizonPercent = 0.5:

horizonPercent = 0.8:

I assume this involves some math to calculate the intersection of the camera's far plane with the floor, but I'm not sure where to start.
